# Yeoman office generator not able to clone libxml2 repo on Windows 7

Tags: git, office365, yeoman, office-js, yo

I am trying to create office add-in using the yeoman generator. I am following the instructions at 
https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/get-started/create-an-office-add-in-using-any-editor.

On executing `yo office`, I am getting the following error.

```
Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true submodule -q update --init --recursive
fatal: https://git.gnome.org/libxml2/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
Clone of 'git://git.gnome.org/libxml2' into submodule path 'libxml2' failed
```

Here is the complete log:

```
d:\Projects\295_Office365ExcelAddin\myHelloWorldaddin>yo office

     _-----_     ?──────────────────────────?
    |       |    │   Welcome to the Office  │
    |--(o)--|    │   Project generator, by  │
   `---------'   │ @OfficeDev! Let's create │
    ( _'U`_ )    │    a project together!   │
    /___A___\   /?──────────────────────────?
     |  ~  |
   __'.___.'__
 '   `  |° ' Y `

? Project name (display name): myHelloWorldaddin
? Root folder of project? Default to current directory
 (d:\Projects\295_Office365ExcelAddin\myHelloWorldaddin), or specify relative path
 from current (src / public):  .
? Office project type: Task Pane Add-in
? Supported Office applications: Excel
? Technology to use: HTML, CSS & JavaScript
   create bower.json
   create package.json
   create tsd.json
   create .bowerrc
   create gulpfile.js
   create content\Office.css
   create images\close.png
   create images\logo-filled.png
   create scripts\MicrosoftAjax.js
   create jsconfig.json
   create tsconfig.json
   create manifest-myhelloworldaddin.xml
   create manifest.xsd
   create app\app.css
   create app\app.js
   create app\home\home.html
   create app\home\home.css
   create app\home\home.js
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: fatal: https://git.gnome.org/libxml2/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info
on the server?
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive: Clone of 'git://git.gnome.org/libxml2' into submodule path 'libxml2' failed
npm ERR! git submodule -q update --init --recursive:
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "D:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true submodule -q update --init --recursive
npm ERR! fatal: https://git.gnome.org/libxml2/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
npm ERR! Clone of 'git://git.gnome.org/libxml2' into submodule path 'libxml2' failed
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     d:\Projects\295_Office365ExcelAddin\myHelloWorldaddin\npm-debug.log
```

Any clue why this might be happening?

**Edit:** 
Git protocol is blocked in my workplace so I have added the following in my `.gitconfig`.

```
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = "git://"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `https` url for git://git.gnome.org/libxml2 is NOT https://git.gnome.org/libxml2. It is [https://git.gnome.org/**browse**/libxml2](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2)

Finally I ended up adding the following to my `.gitconfig` file.

```
[url "https://git.gnome.org/browse/"]
    insteadOf = "git://git.gnome.org/"
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = "git://"
```

With these settings, it is working fine.

Comment: Strange..  https://git.gnome.org/libxml2 actually resolves into  https://git.gnome.org//browse/libxml2 when I try to hit it in browser. Do you know what git version you are running?

Comment: I have only seen 'git submodule sync && git submodule update --init --recursive' this command fail when there is firewall/proxy issues. Also does 'cd /tmp/ && git clone git://git.gnome.org/libxml2' do anything?

Comment: @BethPan I am using "git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1"

Comment: @BethPan 
`d:\tmp2>git clone git://git.gnome.org/libxml2

Cloning into 'libxml2'...

fatal: unable to connect to git.gnome.org:
git.gnome.org[0: 209.132.180.184]: errno=No error` This is **without** the `insteadOf` settings in the gitconfig.

Comment: @BethPan Note that `git` protocol is blocked at my workplace. `curl http://github.com:9418` prints `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`. Will it be possible for you to reproduce the issue by temporarily blocking the 9418 port?

Comment: `git clone https://git.gnome.org/libxml2` gives error : `fatal: https://git.gnome.org/libxml2/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?`

Comment: `git clone https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2` successfully clones the directory.

Comment: Ahh yes blocking port 9418 will totally do it. It's normally the security/firewall/proxy settings on different machines. Glad you found the work around. :) On a separate note, not for this specific reason but xml2js library will not be included in the upcoming update anyways.